# Google Sheet Script Editor: Copy and Paste Rows

Tags: google-sheets, copy-paste, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to switch from Excel to Google Sheets and having a load of trouble. I can't even find a simple guide or "how to".

All I want to do is copy rows 8:12 on "Sheet16" and paste them on row 9 on "Sheet16" (just shift the data down one row).

So far I have this code but it doesn't appear to be doing anything.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet16");
  var copyRange = sheet.getRange("B8:TE12");
  var pasteRange = sheet.getRange( "B9");
}
```

If anyone could give me a hand that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you learn at first java-script and get some experience how to write a function and how to interact with an API and what is an array, after that i will be more easy for you to write some simple scripts :)

for example your code do nothing because it's nothing written about "doing something" there is just written something about "read something"

anyways here is a simple copy/paste script

```
function myFunction() { 
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //access to the spreadsheet
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet16')); //access to the sheet by name
 var range = sheet.getRange('B8'); //assign the range you want to copy
 var copy = range.getValues();
 sheet.getRange('B9').setValue(copy) //new range you want to paste a value
}
```

i hope this will give you an idea of an staring point, if you want to copy range and so on...you need to understand about arrays, thats why javascript first will help alot!